# How to receive house number from android.location.Address object?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

```
List<Address> addresses = new Geocoder(a).getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 1);
Address adr = addresses.get(0)

//receive different paramters of an address
postalCode = a.getPostalCode();
city = a.getLocality();
county = a.getAdminArea();
country = a.getCountryName();
street = a.getThoroughfare();
```

**But how to I receive the house number?**

*NB! a.getAddressLine(0) returns street name with number in a single string (ex: MyAddress 101b). Is there way to receive only the house number (ex: 101b)?*

Comment: Very often address is approximate and doesn't contain house number. My previous research showed that there is no dedicated field for house number. You have to check address string with e.g. regex to find out does it contain number.

Comment: This is really strange from google to not add parameter for house number only. They definitely have the data but why are they giving it out only as a single string together with street name, that bothers me. @Maxim add answer to this question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very often address is approximate and doesn't contain house number. Especially if location is not in the North America or western Europe. My previous research showed that there is no dedicated field for house number. You have to check address string with e.g. regex to find out if it contains house number.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `a.getSubThoroughfare()` returns house number (or `null` if it's address without number). Maybe it depends on locale, so check if it will work for you.

Answer (score -2):

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
String result = null;
try {
    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
    latitude, longitude, 1);
    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) 
    {
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // House no and street name
        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(0)).append(""); 
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, you devoted me.but the code i used that is showing with house no. thats why